# Are dative governing verbs in IE languages mainly inherited from PIE, or later developed within each IE language?

Tags: historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, cases

Some typical dative governing verbs in many IE case-inflecting languages are "help", "give" etc.. Are they mainly inherited from PIE or are they developed within each language? If the latter, is there any case where two IE case-inflecting languages have a highly non-coincident lexicon of dative requiring verbs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is natural for a language that has the Dative case to use this case after verbs that have their action addressed for / to[wards] somebody or something, like “to help” and “to give”. In Russian, the corresponding verbs *помочь* and *дать* are also dative-governing, although the verbs themselves are definitely *not* etymological cognates of the German “helfen” (to help) and “geben” (to give) that govern Dative, it is the semantics of the verbs that suggests using the Dative case with them.

Still, the meaning of the Dative case in some languages can be paired with actions for which quite different governing is used in some other languages. I can compare German and Russian – I can speak both of them, and both of them have dative-governing verbs.

[This page](https://speakasap.com/ru/de-ru/grammar/glagol-dativ/) on a language learning site lists 36 most common German verbs that require Dative. Out of these 36 verbs, 10 verbs require another case or use a preposition + a case in Russian. 10 out of 36 is 27.8% which is almost one third:

- ähneln **D** (to resemble *smb/smth**) — *быть похожим* **на Acc.**
- beitreten **D** (to join *organization*) — *вступать* **в Acc.**
- danken **D** (to thank *smb*) — *благодарить* **Acc.**
- folgen **D** (to follow *smb/smth*) — *следовать* **за Instr.**
- gehorchen **D** (to obey *smb*) — *слушаться* **Gen.**
- gratulieren **D** (to congratulate, greet *smb*) — *поздравлять* **Acc.**
- sich nähern **D** (to approach *smb/smth*) — *приближаться* **к D.**
- passieren **D** (to happen *with smb/smth*) — *случаться* **с Instr.**
- zuhören **D** (to listen *to smb/smth*) — *слушать* **Acc.**
- zustimmen  **D** (to agree *with smb/smth*) — *соглашаться* **с Instr.**

---

* *smb/smth* = *somebody/something*

Comment: this answer doesn't really answer the question, which is too broad because, while "mainly" is not defined, I would take it either as *in the majority of cases* or, perhaps more interesting, as *originally*. Still it quenches some curiosity, but it should be expected that Russian with more cases available would have greater variety which collapsed in German, as most examples have Dativ following the prep. *zu*, obviously in the last 2, but also in *zum Geburtstag gratulieren*, *dazu gehören* whence *gehorchen*, maybe more, equivalent to English *to*, indeed "ähnlich … Englisch"? Or *be-, bei-*.

Comment: @vectory - _**Jemandem** gratuliern_ – that's the Dative which is meant, it's explained in the word list (to congratulate, greet _smb_). Also, _hör **mir** zu_, but not _gehören_. What are you talking about?

Comment: *danken* is weird as refl. *sich bedanken bei* has redundant *be-*, cp. perhaps *be thankful* (but not \* *bethank by*) and there's the usual Accusativ-Dativ alternation "danke *dem* Mann für *den* Apfel". **folgen* has agreement with place, *folge dem Mann zu dem Haus*, but different depending on preposition, e.g. *in das Haus*. We can also see that dat. *mir* often translates *to me* w.r.t. possession, belonging, Ger. *das gehört [zu] mir*. However, the reflexive pronoun doesn't compare, *Sie ähneln dat.sich*. And what about *help*? In Latin *adiuta*, Fr. *aide* the *ad-* is right built-in!

Comment: what am I doing? I'm guessing at the diachrony of course. And about grammar, if agreement and distinction is relevant, e.g. *geben* "give" with the default accusative for the given thing, and dative only for the receiver, so that *typically dative governing* is questionable anyhow. Note though that *geben* has *be-* built right in, too, if I am not mistaken. PS: w.r.t. *in das Haus* note *in's* is more common and as such perhaps akin to *into* (~ \*inz).

Comment: or from the proto-paradigm \*so ~ \*to